# How to display my facebook personal news feed in a intranet site?

Tags: facebook

I'm new to facebook integration. I want to develop an intranet site which can display my personal news feed or timeline by selection. I searched for this but getting tips only for displaying a page newsfeeds and likes. But I need it for personal newsfeed.
Thanks.

Comment: I want something like flipboard app showing personal newsfeed and timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it can be retrieved using graph API with 'read_stream' permission

https://graph.facebook.com/[YOUR_ID]/home